# Rails clean up folder every hour

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a folder within the `public` directory of my Rails project. Sometimes the server downloads files into this folder. I would like the server to clear this folder (delete all the files) every hour. Is it possible to do in Rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a CRON tab and execute it every hour. Something like

```
0 * * * * find /path/to/rails/public -name "*.txt" -mtime +1 | xargs rm -fr
```

Of course, replace `*.txt` with a pattern that matches your files.

Edit: @JoeFrambach has an issue with piping `find` to `xargs` but he doesnt elaborate WHY or offer an alternative solution. If you didn't want to use the pipe you can use the `-exec` switch with `find`:

`find /path/to/rails/public -name "*.txt" -mtime +1 -exec rm {} \;`

Which ultimately should be the same.

Comment: Thank you, Cody. I'm wondering why `-mtime +1` is needed (Does it mean searching for all files modified within last 24 hours?) Also, should it be `-name` instead of `--name`?

Comment: @JoeFrambach your linked article still says why NOT. I'm unable to replicate the `rm: missing operand` issue on OS X or Linux - the article is from 2007 - since been updated?

Answer (score 0):

Not in rails directly, but certainly with a little ruby. You can setup periodic jobs by writing a cron task (or use the whenever gem to keep it in ruby if you don't like cron).

You can use whenever to execute shell commands directly, or alternatively write a rake task and execute that instead.